# SQL Server Report 2008 R2 Report Services - debug a custom assembly

Tags: debugging, dll, visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2008

How do I debug an assembly that's being used by a Report Services report running through SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services?

- I'm trying to debug using VS2012
- It looks like the reports were created in VS2008 (VS9)
- The assembly is targeted to .NET 3.5
- I'm developing on my own dev machine and want to debug on this
- One of the expressions in my report calls a method in a custom .dll
- I've built the dll in debug mode, and deployed it, plus the .pdb file, to the default location (in my case, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies)
- I'm setting the breakpoint in VS2012 for the assembly code, which is contained in a distinct project
- I run up the report in Firefox, then attach to the ReportingServicesService.exe process
- I carry out some actions in the report that should trigger the code
- The breakpoint isn't hit

Is there anything else I need to do to debug?

Comment: "•I run up the report in Firefox," - tried IE?

Comment: Thanks Mitch - I've answered my own question now, however that's possibly an important point if you're using the report viewer that's usually available at localhost/ReportServer_SQL2008. In my case I was originally running up an .aspx page that has the report embedded as a control, so it should be triggering the report server anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.  Here's what else I needed to do:

- Open the report solution in VS2008
- Open the custom assembly project in VS2012
- Attach to process from VS2012, but attach to devenv.exe for the VS2008 instance
- Click the report 'preview' tab in VS2008 - this runs the report, which is now hooked up to the VS2012 debugger :)

Here's some MSFT documentation on this (doesn't strictly relate to SQL Server 2008 R2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153693.aspx